# Calculation Not Displaying Correctly In Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to asp.net MVC and have a question on the Razor View.

I'm having some issues display the result of a calculation

I have the following code:

```
 foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr class="ourProduct">
                <td>
                    <div class="ourProductDesc">
                        <h4>
                            @item.Description
                        </h4>

                        <div class="ourPrice">
                            <span>£ @item.price</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="ourPrice">
                    £ @item.Quantity * item.price
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to do this calculation and display the results as expected. Currently I am getting an incorrect output:

£ 1 * item.Prod.price

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there - you just have to wrap the calculation inside (  )

Also when writing HTML instead of writng £ you should use "&pound" - There are lots of special characters and codes - Here's a useful site for a list of characters and codes:  http://character-code.com/

Back to your orginal question:

Update your code to the following and it should work as expected:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr class="ourProduct">
                <td>
                    <div class="ourProductDesc">
                        <h4>
                            @item.Description
                        </h4>

                        <div class="ourPrice">
                            <span>&pound; @item.price</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td class="ourPrice">
                    &pound; @(item.Quantity * item.price)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it worked perfectly. p.s thanks for website reference

Comment: @somango No problem, glad i could help! If you ever feel stuck or need some pointers to learning resources you can always PM me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the razor code calculation part inside `@()` as shown :-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr class="ourProduct">
            <td>
                <div class="ourProductDesc">
                    <h4>
                        @item.Description
                    </h4>

                    <div class="ourPrice">
                        <span>£ @item.price</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="ourPrice">
                £ @(item.Quantity * item.price) // correct here
            </td>
        </tr>
  }
```

and instead of `£` you can use `&pound`.